# Фото не загружается

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! У меня код - обработчик объявления. На тестовом сервере все хорошо работало, а как загрузила на хостинг, не работают проверки на размер и на формат загружаемого фото, да и сама фотография в папку не загружается и в базу не записывается. Напишите, пожалуйста, подробней, что не так. Я php недавно занимаюсь.

```
include("blocks/bd.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT sum FROM comments_setting", $db);
$myrow  = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $title = stripslashes($title);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);
    $title = trim($title);
    if ($title == '') {
        unset($title);
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['meta_d'])) {
    $meta_d = $_POST['meta_d'];
    $meta_d = stripslashes($meta_d);
    $meta_d = htmlspecialchars($meta_d);
    $meta_d = trim($meta_d);
    if ($meta_d == '') {
        unset($meta_d);
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['meta_k'])) {
    $meta_k = $_POST['meta_k'];
    $meta_k = stripslashes($meta_k);
    $meta_k = htmlspecialchars($meta_k);
    $meta_k = trim($meta_k);
    if ($meta_k == '') {
        unset($meta_k);
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $date = stripslashes($date);
    $date = htmlspecialchars($date);
    $date = trim($date);
    if ($date == '') {
        unset($date);
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $text = stripslashes($text);
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
    $text = trim($text);
    if ($text == '') {
        unset($text);
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['pochta'])) {
    $pochta = $_POST['pochta'];
    $pochta = stripslashes($pochta);
    $pochta = htmlspecialchars($pochta);
    $pochta = trim($pochta);
    if ($pochta == '') {
        unset($pochta);
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['tel'])) {
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $tel = stripslashes($tel);
    $tel = htmlspecialchars($tel);
    $tel = trim($tel);
}

if (isset($_POST['gorod'])) {
    $gorod = $_POST['gorod'];
    $gorod = stripslashes($gorod);
    $gorod = htmlspecialchars($gorod);
    $gorod = trim($gorod);
    if ($gorod == '') {
        unset($gorod);
    }
}

if (isset($_FILES['foto'])) {
    $foto = $_FILES['foto'];
}

if (isset($_POST['pr'])) {
    $pr = $_POST['pr'];
    $pr = stripslashes($pr);
    $pr = htmlspecialchars($pr);
    $pr = trim($pr);
}

if (isset($_POST['sub_ob'])) {
    $sub_ob = $_POST['sub_ob'];
}

function isSecurity($foto)
{
    $name = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
    $type = $_FILES['foto']['type'];
    $size = $_FILES['foto']['size'];

    $blacklist = array(
        ".php",
        ".phtml",
        ".php3",
        ".php4"
    );
    foreach ($blacklist as $item) {
        if (preg_match("/$item\$/i", $name))
            exit("<p>Такие типы файлов недопустимы! <input name='back' type='button' value='Вернуться назад' onclick='javascript:self.back();'></p>");
    }

    if (($type != "image/gif") && ($type != "image/png") && ($type != "image/jpg") && ($type != "image/jpeg") && ($type != ""))
        exit("<p>Такие форматы недопустимы! Можно загружать изображения в формате: gif, png, jpg, jpeg. <input name='back' type='button' value='Вернуться назад' onclick='javascript:self.back();'></p>");

    if ($size > 100 * 1024) {
        exit("<p>Такие размеры недопустимы! Размер фотографии должен быть меньше 100 кб. <input name='back' type='button' value='Вернуться назад' onclick='javascript:self.back();'></p>");
    }

    return true;
}

function LoadFoto($foto)
{
    $type      = $_FILES['foto']['type'];
    $name      = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
    $uploaddir = "avatars/";
    $name      = md5(microtime()) . "." . substr($type, strlen("image/"));
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $name)) {
        return $name;
    } else
        return false;
}

if ($name = LoadFoto($foto)) {
    // Использовать переменную $name
} else {
    // Не удалось сохранить файл
}

if (isSecurity($foto))
    LoadFoto($foto);
else
    $message = "Ошибка при загрузке фото!";
```

Comment: Проверьте права на папку "avatars/" - скорее всего, нет прав на запись. А на счет сохранения в БД ничего не скажу - не вижу в коде никаких намеков на вставку записи.

Comment: Спасибо, а почему проверки на размер и на формат не работают? На php файл проверка проходит.

Comment: Убедитесь, что `$_FILES["foto"]["error"] == 0`. Или посмотрите, какой код ошибки возвращается.

Comment: GoodLine  
Не:  

    $title = stripslashes($title);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);
    $title = trim($title);
а:  

    $title = trim(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($title)));

Comment: Спасибо, изменила права, но фото все равно не загружается, значит, ошибка в коде...

Comment: @ReinRaus, от такой "оптимизации" только читабельность ухудшилась, а возможность sql-инъекции осталась. Лучше бы предложили это код в функцию свернуть - больше бы было пользы от коммента.

@Регина, какой код выдает `$_FILES["foto"]["error"]`?

Comment: А еще Ваш код уязвим к заливке шелла или произвольного любого контента.  
Самый простой пример: можно отправить файл html с Content-Type: image/png, Ваш скрипт сохранит это в папку аватаров и теперь если на сайте будет ссылка вроде «Посмотреть аватар», то пользователь перешедший по ней станет жертвой уязвимости.  
А если сервер в html страницах выполняет PHP, то все вообще ужасно.

Comment: Извините, я не знаю как проверить-то, через echo попробовать вывести? Так ничего не выводится, пробовала вывести :

echo'$_FILES["foto"]["error"]';

echo" $_FILES[foto][name] ";

echo" $_FILES[foto][type] ";

echo" $_FILES[foto][size] ";

Вышло вот что: $_FILES["foto"]["error"] Array[name] Array[type] Array[size].

Comment: @равнодушный, надо настраивать глаза так, чтобы мой пример был читабельнее. Вы не стихи читаете, а код :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, я лишь говорю, что Ваш комментарий бесполезен: он не имеет отношения к вопросу и не решает ни одной из проблем предложенного кода.

@Регина, для вывода значения переменной на экран кавычки не нужны, т.е. нужно было написать:

`echo $_FILES["foto"]["error"];`

В общем, ДО выполнения функции `LoadFoto()` напишите
`die(print_r($_FILES["foto"]));`

И скопируйте результат после загрузки файла.

Comment: Вот: Array ( [name] => tamada.gif [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 6 [size] => 0 ) 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А об оптимизации что-нибудь слышали?

11 одинаковых кусков кода, занимают почти 100 строк, когда можно это все уместить всего в 10 с использованием 1 массива с ключами и 1 цикла for или foraech

```
$mas=array("title","tel","foto" etc);
foreach ($mas as $key)
{
if (isset($_POST[$key])) {
    $name = $_POST[$key];
    $name = stripslashes($gorod);
    $name = htmlspecialchars($gorod);
    $name = trim($gorod);
    if ($name == '') {
        unset($name );
    }
    // ну а переменную $name можно так же заюзать как массив с ключами и значениями и записать все массивом!

}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь ввиду.

Answer (score 4):

Ха, не могу больше писать комментарии...)

Но, ошибка 6 означает, что отсутствует временная папка, т.е. файл грузить некуда. Вывод - проблема на стороне хостинга.

Comment: Вы мне очень помогли!